# Regular expression to look up commercial contracts with a certain structure

Tags: r, regex, string, grepl

could somebody help me with formulating a regex to look up contracts with a certain naming structure?

I need to go through a directory structure and collect pdf files with the naming structure discussed below. I can do the rest but I think using regex would be appropriate collect the files.

I have provided some sample names:

```
 - 126-VE-0178-S-11/39.pdf  
 - 133-GE-0023-S-17.pdf 
 - 274-VE-0132-S-16/01.pdf 
 - AKV01-VE-000982-S-17.pdf 
 - ESZM2-VE-4982-S-13.pfd  
 - HAT-VE-0053-A-13.pdf
```

Structure description:

- The first section is is any number of upper case characters and/or numbers
- Followed by a hyphen
- Second section is either VE or GE
- Followed by a hyphen
- The third section is a number 4+ digits
- Followed by a hyphen
- Fourth section is either S or A
- Followed by a hyphen
- Fifth section is either a number with two digits (denoting year) and optionally a "/" and a number denoting its version number
- Ending with ".pdf"

I hope this makes sense - any help would be appreciated!

Thank you in advance

Comment: Nice tool, e.g.  https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned the explanation already in your question

`([0-9A-Z]+)-(VE|GE)-(\\d{4,})-(S|A)-(\\d){2}(/\\d+)?\\.pdf`

- `+` 1 to infinite occurence
- `(x|y)` match x or y
- `\\d` special character -> digit
- `{4,}` match 4 or more
- `(x)?` match 0 or 1 times
- `\\.` -> "." has to be escaped, because it's a special character (meaning: any character) escaped it's a simple dot

Comment: could you give some kind of explanation to the answer?

Comment: sure, like this way ?

Comment: This is way better! I added the comment since the succinct answer triggered the "low quality posts" flag and the post appeared in the [review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/17446684). Now it is fine, thanks!

Comment: Oh ok, sorry for that! I could have copied half of the question as explanation :D

Answer (score 0):

```
[A-Z0-9]+-(V|G)E-[0-9]{4,}-(S|A)-[0-9]{2}(\/[0-9]+)?\.pdf
```

Looks like the explanation is already in your question. :P
DIY on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/x0GG7n/1)

Test with R:

```
> grepl("[A-Z0-9]+-(V|G)E-[0-9]{4,}-(S|A)-[0-9]{2}(/[0-9]+)?.pdf", "126-VE-0178-S-11/39.pdf", perl=TRUE)
[1] TRUE
```

with use of posix classes:

```
[[:upper:][:digit:]]+-(V|G)E-[[:digit:]]{4,}-(S|A)-[[:digit:]]{2}(\/[[:digit:]]+)?\.pdf
```